# Training design / sequential loading of images for Mask-RCNN

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, data-augmentation

I am training a deep learning model using Mask RCNN from the following git repository: matterport/Mask_RCNN. I rely on a heavy augmentation of my dataset (original dataset: 59 images of 1988x1355x3 with each > 80 annotations), which I store locally (necessary to evaluate type/degree of augmentation vs validation metrics). The augmented dataset counts 6000 images. This dataset varies in x and y dimensions of the image, because of reducing resolution and affine transformations - I assume the different x,y-dimensions will not affect the final tests.

However, my Python kernel crashes whenever I load more than 'X' images to train the model.

Hence, I came up with the idea of splitting the dataset in sub-datasets and iterate through the sub-dataset, using the 'last' trained weights as starting point for the new round. But I am not sure if the results will be the same (read: same, taken the stochastic nature of 'stochastic gradient descent' into account)?

I wonder, if the results would be the same, if I don't iterate through the sub-datasets per epoch, but train Y epochs (eg. 20 for 'heads' only, 10 for 'all layers')?

Yet, I am sure this is not the most efficient way of solving this issues. Ideas for improvement are welcome.

**Note**, I am not using `keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()`, as I have understood it, it randomly generates data and feeds it to the model by replacing the input for the epoch, whereas I would like to feed the whole dataset to the model.

Answer (score 0):

1. I came up with the idea of splitting the dataset in sub-datasets and iterate through the sub-dataset, using the 'last' trained weights as starting point for the new round. But I am not sure if the results will be the same?

   - You are doing the same thing as ImageDataGenerator is doing (creating your own mini-batches) but less optimally. The result will be same with respect to what?

If you mean with respect to a model that was trained with all the data in a single batch? - Most probably not. As a lower batch means slower convergence. But this can be solved by training for more epochs.

Another issue is reproducibility. If you want to reproduce your model with same results each time just use seeds.

```
import random
random.seed(1)

import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

import tensorflow
tensorflow.random.set_seed(1)
```

2. Another concept is gradient accumulation. It will help you train you with high batch size without keeping too many images in memory at a time.

https://github.com/CyberZHG/keras-gradient-accumulation

3. Finally, keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator() in facts trains on the whole dataset, it just chooses a random sample at each step (you're doing the same thing with your so-called sub-datasets).

You can seed the ImageDataGenerator so it is reproducible and not entirely random.